# inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$. What is the inverse Fourier transform of $f$?

Since $f$ is neither a $L^1$-function nor a Schwartz-function I am looking for an inverse Fourier transform in the sense of tempered distributions. I’ve tried several distributions but every single one failed. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Can you find the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$? Then multiplication with $x$ and $y$ inverse-transforms to partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ respectively (times some factor).

Comment: That was just an idea. I hadn't tried it. When I looked at it later I didn't know how to solve it.

Comment: Another idea: In polar coordinates, $f = \cos^3\theta \sin\theta = \frac18 \sin 4\theta + \frac14 \sin 2\theta.$ Could we easily find the (inverse) Fourier transform of $\sin n\theta$? Perhaps it could be used that Fourier transform commutes with rotation.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\frac 1 {2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty
 f(r) e^{i (x, y) \cdot (\xi, \zeta)} dx dy =
\int_0^\infty r f(r) J_0( \rho r) dr.$$
If the one-dimensional functional $r_+^{-3}$ is understood as
$$(r_+^{-3}, f) =
\int_0^\infty r^{-3} \left(
 f(r) - f(0) - f'(0) r - \frac {f''(0)} 2 r^2 H(1 - r) \right) dr,$$
then
$$\mathcal F[r^{-4}] =
\frac {\rho^2} 4 \left( \ln \frac \rho 2 + \gamma - 1 \right), \\
\mathcal F \!\left[ \frac {x^3 y} {(x^2 + y^2)^2} \right] =
\frac {\partial^4} {\partial \xi^3 \partial \zeta} \mathcal F[r^{-4}] =
\frac {\xi \zeta (\xi^2 - 3 \zeta^2)} {(\xi^2 + \zeta^2)^3}.$$
In general, differentiating $r^{-n}$ will produce delta function terms. $\partial \rho^{-2} / \partial \xi$ gives a $\delta^{(1, 0)}(\xi, \zeta)$ term, but $\zeta \delta^{(1, 0)}(\xi, \zeta) = 0$.

It appears that this remarkable relation holds:
$$\mathcal F[\sin 2 k \phi] =
\frac {2(-1)^k |k|} {\rho^2} \sin 2 k \psi,$$
from which the above transform follows immediately, but <s>I have no idea how to derive it</s> the edit box is too narrow for the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I wanna understand your way, I have some questions: It looks like you are using the Hankel transform, right? Is there any name for $r_+^3$? The second equation reminds me somehow of the Bessel differential operator. And how did you get $F(r^{-4})=\frac{\rho^2}{4}(\log(\frac\rho2)+\gamma-1)$?

Comment: Correct, we have
$$e^{i (x, y) \cdot (\xi, \zeta)} = e^{i \rho r \cos(\phi - \psi)}, \\
\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{i \rho r \cos(\phi - \psi)} d\phi =
\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{i \rho r \cos \phi} d\phi =
2 \pi J_0(\rho r),$$
and the Fourier transform of a radial function reduces to the Hankel transform. Then we can find $(r_+^{-3}, J_0(\rho r))$ from the definition of $r_+^{−3}$. Or, since $r_+^{-n}$ is related to analytic continuation of the functional $r_+^\lambda$, $\mathcal F[r^{−4}]$ can also be found as the regular part of $\mathcal F[r^\lambda]$ at $\lambda = −4$: (continued)

Comment: $$(r_+^{-3}, J_0(\rho r)) =
\int_0^\infty r^{-3} \left(
 J_0(\rho r) - 1 + \left( \frac {\rho r} 2 \right)^2 H(1 - r) \right) dr = \\
[(\lambda + 4)^0] \mathcal F[r^\lambda] =
[(\lambda + 4)^0] \frac {\Gamma \!\left( \frac \lambda 2 + 1 \right)}
  {2 \Gamma \!\left( -\frac \lambda 2 \right)}
 \left( \frac \rho 2 \right)^{-\lambda - 2} = \\
\frac {\rho^2} 4 \left( \ln \frac \rho 2  + \gamma - 1 \right).$$
$r^\lambda$ is a two-dimensional functional, $r_+^\lambda$ is a one-dimensional functional. I don't think $r_+^\lambda$ has a name.

Comment: @Maxim Hey, I have a question about the derivative you are taking in your answer. It looks like you are using the identity $\partial^\alpha \mathcal F\bigl[u(x)\bigr](\xi)=\mathcal F\bigl[(ix)^\alpha u(x)\bigr](\xi)$ where $\alpha$ is a multi-index and $x=(x_1,...,x_n),\xi\in\mathbb R^n$, here $n=2$. But why do we get $\delta$ terms in general when we are differentiating $\mathcal F[r^{-k}]$ where $k\in\mathbb N$ and $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$?

Comment: @Ele It also boils down to how we've defined the one-dimensional functional $r_+^{-n}$. Writing out the distributional derivative of $r_+^{-1}$, we get
$$((r_+^{-1})', f) = -(r_+^{-1}, f') =
-\int_0^\infty \frac {f'(r) - f'(0) H(1 - r)} r dr = \\
\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \left(
 -\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac {f(r)} {r^2} dr +
  \frac {f(\epsilon)} \epsilon -
  f'(0) \ln \epsilon \right),$$
while $-r_+^{-2}$ gives (continued)

Comment: $$(-r_+^{-2}, f) =
-\int_0^\infty \frac {f(r) - f(0) - f'(0) r H(1 - r)} {r^2} dr = \\
\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \left(
 -\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac {f(r)} {r^2} dr +
  \frac {f(0)} \epsilon - f'(0) \ln \epsilon \right),$$
and we can see that the results differ by
$$\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}
 \frac {f(\epsilon) - f(0)} \epsilon = f'(0),$$
therefore
$$(r_+^{-1})' = -r_+^{-2} - \delta'(r).$$

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of $\sin k \phi$ for $k \in \mathbb N$ can be derived in this manner:
$$I_k = \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{i \rho r \cos(\phi - \psi)} \sin k \phi \,d\phi =
\sin k \psi \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{i \rho r \cos \phi} \cos k \phi \,d\phi =
2 \pi i^k \sin k \psi \,J_k(\rho r), \\
\mathcal F \!\left[ \frac {\sin k \phi} {r^2} \right] =
\frac 1 {2 \pi} \int_0^\infty \frac {I_k} r dr =
i^k \sin k \psi \int_0^\infty \frac {J_k(r)} r dr =
\frac {i^k \sin k \psi} k.$$
Since
$$\frac {x^3 y} {(x^2 + y^2)^2} = \frac {2 \sin 2 \phi + \sin 4 \phi} 8, \\
\frac {\xi \zeta(\xi^2 - 3 \zeta^2)} {(\xi^2 + \zeta^2)^3} =
\frac {\sin 4 \psi - \sin 2 \psi} {2 \rho^2},$$
the desired result follows.